# I think I configured AppFabric correctly but nothing is happening on AppFabric dashboard

Tags: appfabric

I have setup AppFabric and both monitoring and persistance configurations (just in case ) for SQL Server 2008 DB.
In my service application I can see that it has default monitoring level so events should be monitored, I use my WCF service - make various calls, but when I check dashboard it shows 0 0 0 everywhere.

Is there something else that should be setup ? I dont get any errors anywhere when I use AppFa bric configurations in IIS control panel so it appears that everything is supposed to be up and running. I use latest version of appfabric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly make sure the AppFabric Event Collection Service is running - which moves events from ETW to the staging table (ASStagingTable) within the monitoring database. 
Make sure the  account the service is running under is a member of the ASMonitoringDbAdmin SQL database role - which will make sure the service has the rights to emit events to the database (i.e. from ETW to the database).

If all of the above is ok, then you should have data in the ASStagingTable (which is a table in the monitoring database).

The next place to look is AppFabric's SQL Agent Jobs. Make sure they are running without any errors. They are responsible for moving data from the staging table to the appropriate event table depending on the event type. The AppFabric dashboard queries the event specific tables.

If this is running ok, then you should have data in the event tables - e.g. ASWcfEventsTable if you emitting events from a WCF service.

Lastly, if all of the above is golden, check out the event log for AppFabric, which is located: Application and Services Logs --> Microsoft --> Windows -->Application Server-Applications. Make sure the log is enabled by right clicking on the Admin node and selecting Enable Log.

The other possibility is that your account isn't a member of the ASMonitoringDbReader SQL database role, which is required for observers to view data through the dashboard.

Comment: sorry I never fixed it, and tried this question on different server (official appfabric forums ) and their replies didnt help so I cannot say whether its the right answer

Comment: no problem - if you ever get around to trying again, the collection service, and the sql agent job are the main two areas to check.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick comment, since I got a similar problem and after an extensive research I found the problem is:
 when running SQLServer2008 Express, the SQL Agent is not working properly [see here](http://sqlserver.livejournal.com/67400.html)

So I **have** to run the SP ( *exec [ASImportEvents]* ) manually ...