# Configuring AppFabric Monitoring - The SQL Agent Service that runs jobs for this database could not be detected

Tags: sql-server-2008, appfabric, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I'm trying to resolve why a couple of our servers which has app fabric installed isn't logging to a database.

We have multiple web servers running 2008 R2, and one database server 2008 R2 with SQL Server 2008.  Each web server has AppFabric installed, and is configured to log monitoring to separate databases on the database server.

All the web servers are logging correctly except two.  I have tried re-configuring the AppFabric monitoring configuration many times, and each time it gives me an error:

> The SQL Agent Service that runs jobs for this database could not be detected. The AppFabricDashboard will not display event data if the service is stopped.

I get this error when I register the monitoring store in the root web.config, and initialize the monitoring store.  It successfully creates all the database tables, sql jobs etc.  **But nothing seems to log**.

And yes, the sql agent service is running, because it is the same sql agent service for all other databases on the database server.

---

I'm using the same settings on all the web servers except for the unique database.

My monitoring configuration is:

AppFabric Event Collection Service Account: **srv_AppFabric**
Monitoring provider: **System.Data.SqlClient**
Connection String: **ApplicationServerMonitoringConnectionString**
Server: **sql2008** (this is the name of our database server)
Database: **ApplicationServerMonitoring_DEV** (each web server connects to a different database which will be ApplicationServerMonitoring_[Env])

Security Configuration:

Windows Authentication
Administrators: **srv_AppFabric**
Readers: **srv_AppFabric**
Writers: **srv_AppFabric**

---

I've followed some solutions to similar issues to no avail:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637694(v=azure.10).aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733348/configuring-appfabric-with-remote-database
- [I think I configured AppFabric correctly but nothing is happening on AppFabric dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508576/i-think-i-configured-appfabric-correctly-but-nothing-is-happening-on-appfabric-d)
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-server-appfabric-troubleshooting-anonymous-logon.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dublin/thread/e885b0cb-29c8-42b2-a8a7-f6373b3dfb12/

Would appreciate any help or suggestions, thanks

Comment: Wow, three years have gone by and no replies.  we are seeing exactly the same problem, with nowhere to turn.  Another cryptic Microsoft error with no help.